Regexp: Regexp that matches ")" but NOT "()"
I am writing a function that needs to move the character back to the first ")" character. However, in the middle there might be a "()" characters, I do NOT want the cursor to go there.
HOWEVER, if there are no "()" characters, then I simply want to go to the first ")"
How could I go about doing this? My first instinct was using regex or rx; but I am a complete regex novice.
Btw here's an example:
fn this_is_a_function(args) -> Result<(), Err<Bla>> {                          
}

I want the re-search-backwards function to match the ")" after args and ignore the ")" in Result<(), ...
I tried using "[^(])" but if fails in this example:
fn this_is_a_function() { 

}                         

When you call the re-search-backwards with that regexp, you get the following error
foo: Search failed: "[^(])"

It sounds like you can search for [^(]) and then move point to the last position of that match.

Hi phils, thanks for the reply. I've edited the question to showcase the problem better.

Read the docstring for re-search-backward, and pay attention to the NOERROR argument (described by the linked re-search-forward).
